# Solution fails to pass one test with large inputs?

Tags: javascript

```
function birthdayCakeCandles(n, ar) {
    // Complete this function
    ar.sort();
    var biggestNo = ar[(ar.length - 1)];
    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
        if (ar[i] === biggestNo)
            total++;
    }
    return total;
}
```

Here's the problem - https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/birthday-cake-candles/problem

Comment: Add the problem to the question. See [ask].

Comment: What input fails? What is the error?

Comment: No error This one https://hr-testcases-us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com/23074/input08.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJ4WZFDFQTZRGO3QA&Expires=1505061874&Signature=6AkLjPl8SUoSjD9uzuqawV4yn50%3D&response-content-type=text%2Fplain

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to sort the array, you can do the problem in ***O(n)*** times

```
function birthdayCakeCandles(arr, n) {
    var total = 0;
    var len = arr.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (ar[i] === n) 
            total++;
    }
    return total;
```